# Erro ao usar o System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(“%{DOWN}”)

Tags: c#, winforms, método, calendar

Em um aplicação windows form tenho um DateTimePicker e eu não quero que ele exiba a data então fiz o seguinte:

```
public CadNovoPagamento()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    dtpEmissao.Value = DateTime.Now;
    dtpEmissao.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dtpEmissao.CustomFormat = " ";
}

private void dtpEmissao_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtpEmissao.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}

private void dtpEmissao_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    String teste = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || teste == "\t")
    {
        dtpEmissao.Text = dtpEmissao.Value.ToString();
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
private void dtpEmissao_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
}

private void dtpEmissao_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtpVencimento.Text != "" && txtDias.Text != "")
    {
        DateTime datavencimento = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpVencimento.Text);
        DateTime dataemissao = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEmissao.Text);
        //Instância do TimeSpan recebendo a subtração entre as datas
        TimeSpan ts = datavencimento.Subtract(dataemissao);

        txtDias.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString();
    }
}
```

Porem, quando ele entra no método dtpEmissao_Enter o computador trava e fica travado até abrir o gerenciador de tarefas.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Um observação em uma maquina o erro não acontece.

Comment: um datetimepicker, e vc nao quer que exiba a data ?! explique melhor por favor

Comment: seu código está bem estranho. Porque ao instanciar o `form`, coloca o custom format como `" "` e depois no evento `ValueChanged` você defime o custom format ?! Depois no `keypress`, você define o `Text` do controle sendo igual ao seu `value`...  e por fim, você pega o `Text` do datetimepicker, converte pra `DateTime` (oi?!) pra calcular um TimeStamp

Comment: sim preciso que ao abrir a tela o datetimepicker venha assim  __/__/____ porque esse não é um campo obrigatório, logo se eu trago com a data de hoje ao gravar ele grava com a data de hoje e necessariamente não é data de hoje.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer esse "Show CheckBox" e/ou a MaskedTextBox  para não usar mais essa gambiarra?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis você sabe qual a Properties devo marcar?

Comment: veja a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem entrar na questão do `SendKeys`, acho que a resolução pro seu problema pode ser mais simples:

Altere as properties do seu DateTimePicker:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]